# Building error in the Unity Asset Hexplanet Pro

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, namespaces

Yesterday I purchased the Unity Asset Hexplanet Pro which is working fine in the editor.

But whenever I try to build for Android, I get the following errors at PlanetVertexData 13, 6

```
"The namespace name 'Menu Item' could not be found" & "The namespace name 'Menu Item Attribute' could not be found".
```

I already tried typing `#if UNITY_EDITOR` at the beginning of the file and `#endif` at the end but that didn't do anything.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Try to write to the creator of this Assets

Comment: I did a week ago, but I didn't get an answer. Hopefully he'll read it soon.